# При использовании `plt.plot()` в цикле получается пустое окно

Tags: python, numpy, графика, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Пытаюсь построить круг в jupyterlab:

```
import matplotlib
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

i = 0
inc = 0.1
Z = 0
R = 50
while i < 360:
    X = R * cos(radians(i))
    Y = R * sin(radians(i))
    plt.plot (X,Y)
    i = i + inc
```

... а в результате выводится пустое окно. Также в Spyder выдает пустое окно.
 В чем здесь ошибка ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.plot()` ожидает два массива координат - координаты по оси `X` и координаты по оси `Y`:

```
i = 0
inc = 0.1
Z = 0
R = 50
X = []
Y = []
while i < 360:
    X.append(R * cos(radians(i)))
    Y.append(R * sin(radians(i)))
    i += inc

plt.plot(X, Y)
```

---

но гораздо проще будет воспользоваться векторизированными (без использования циклов) функциями из модуля [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/quickstart.html) вместо скалярных функций из модуля `math`:

```
import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy

R = 50
n_points = 3600

i = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, n_points))
X = R * np.cos(i)
Y = R * np.sin(i)
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

PS также векторизированные функции из Numpy обычно работают на порядки быстрее циклов с использованием функций из `math`. Особенно это заметно на больших (1000+) массивах данных.

---

Результат в обоих случаях одинаковый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]